# Issue with mongodump command

Tags: mongodb

When i am running the mongodump command its saying "done dumping" but actually the dump folder is not getting created in the bin. Below is the message that got generated.

```
 C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin>mongodump --db epfparser
2015-08-12T18:17:04.722+0530    writing epfparser.system.indexes to dump\epfpars
er\system.indexes.bson
2015-08-12T18:17:04.723+0530    writing epfparser.users2 to dump\epfparser\users
2.bson
2015-08-12T18:17:07.720+0530    [........................]  epfparser.users2  21
82/118555  (1.8%)
2015-08-12T18:17:10.720+0530    [#.......................]  epfparser.users2  54
32/118555  (4.6%)
2015-08-12T18:17:13.720+0530    [#.......................]  epfparser.users2  81
55/118555  (6.9%)
2015-08-12T18:17:16.720+0530    [##......................]  epfparser.users2  10
158/118555  (8.6%)
2015-08-12T18:17:19.720+0530    [##......................]  epfparser.users2  12
214/118555  (10.3%)
2015-08-12T18:17:22.719+0530    [##......................]  epfparser.users2  14
229/118555  (12.0%)
2015-08-12T18:17:25.721+0530    [###.....................]  epfparser.users2  16
174/118555  (13.6%)
2015-08-12T18:17:28.720+0530    [######..................]  epfparser.users2  30
913/118555  (26.1%)
2015-08-12T18:17:31.782+0530    [#############...........]  epfparser.users2  68
011/118555  (57.4%)
2015-08-12T18:17:34.720+0530    [##################......]  epfparser.users2  89
902/118555  (75.8%)
2015-08-12T18:17:37.732+0530    [####################....]  epfparser.users2  10
2472/118555  (86.4%)
2015-08-12T18:17:40.719+0530    [#######################.]  epfparser.users2  11
6994/118555  (98.7%)
2015-08-12T18:17:41.523+0530    writing epfparser.users2 metadata to dump\epfpar
ser\users2.metadata.json
2015-08-12T18:17:41.549+0530    done dumping epfparser.users2
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mongodump --db dbname –out d:\
```

where dbname is the name of your database, and d:\ is the output directory.